# How to Load More / Infinite Scroll to Nuxt3 graphql WordPress

Tags: wordpress, graphql, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I' m trying to understand how to paginate a query made under nuxt3, calling a graphql WordPress endpoint. I have digged into this on Nuxt2 succefully, but i cannot replicate.

inside my index i have this script code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute()
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const { data, refresh, pending } = await useFetch(config.public.wordpressUrl, {
  method: 'get',
  query: {
    query: `
     query NewQuery {
        posts(first:10){
          pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
              hasPreviousPage
              endCursor
              startCursor
          }
         nodes {
           title
           date
           uri
         }
       }
     }`
  },

  transform(data) {

    return data.data.posts.nodes as Array<Record<'title' | 'date' | 'excerpt' | 'uri' | 'featuredImage', string>>;
  }
});

</script>
```

and my template part:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <TheHeader></TheHeader>
    {{ data }}
    <div class="grid gap-8 grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 p-6">
      <Post v-for="post in data" :key="post.uri" :post="post"></Post>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

i have a component called Post.vue that display the posts. everything run smooth, but how can i add a load more button? or infinite scroll to load more posts?

the code come from a tutorial/repository here: https://github.com/JEverhart383/nuxt-wordpress-starter

any help is really appreciated ;) i cannot find any infos-documentation or similar.

Tried to merge this codebase: https://github.com/kylewberg/portfolio-on-nuxtjs/blob/main/pages/index.vue that is made under nuxt2.